# Avoiding keyword stuffing in SOLR

Tags: solr, keyword

I'm looking for a way to limit the effect (or eliminate it) of "keyword stuffing" in SOLR.  (We're currently running a SOLR 6.2.0 server).
I've tried setting omitTermFreqAndPositions="true", but when I do that, some queries throw phrase query errors (specifically queries with search terms such as G1966B - likely due to word splitting and such).  I could go down the road of disabling the word splitting and try to avoid the phrase query errors, but this is simply going to mess up more things than I'm trying to fix.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to limit the affect of multiple keyword matches in a single field?

Example:  If we have a description field with something like this:

> BrandX 1200 Series G1924B LC/MSD SL XBC System.
>   This BrandX 1200 Series G1924B ( G 1924 B , G1924 B , G 1924B ) LC/MSD SL XBC >System is in excellent condition.

When someone does a search for "G1924B" I would like to avoid scoring this document higher just because it happens to have G1924B (or a variation of that) in there several times.
In theory someone could repeat the keyword many times in their description to try to trick the system into ranking their search results higher.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens to appear as a more frequent requirement than initially thought.
If you remove both term freq and positions, you lose phrase search capability.

I would recommend to write a custom similarity that ignores TF ( Term Frequency).
At the moment the default BM25 take TF in consideration.
You can just pick that class and adjust the similarity calculus to consider TF as a constant.

e.g.

org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity.BM25DocScorer#score

[1] org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity

Comment: Thanks Alessandro.  I've never done anything like write a custom similarity, but I will start exploring that option.  Any tips or good places to get started on this road would be appreciated.

Comment: It is actually quite simple to develop such a new similarity :
Let's assume you start from TF/IDF ( this is probably a good assumption for your use case) :

1) write your ConstantTfSimilarity to extend : org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity
For example you may just override the  public float tf(float freq) {
    return (float)Math.sqrt(freq);
  }
2) override org.apache.solr.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarityFactory to return your custom similarity
3) set it in the schema